# SSIS package on server cannot export to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have create a SSIS package which works perfectly from my BIDS. But when executing from the server it fails.

The package does the following:

- Insert data (read from the SQL database) into an Excel file
- Via a VB-script it opens the Excel file and removes line number 2

I can see that the package can insert the data correct in the Excel file. It fails when executing the VB-Script in a step called "Remove 2nd line":

```
Remove 2ndline: Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

The script is:

```
    #Region "Help:  Introduction to the script task"
    'The Script Task allows you to perform virtually any operation that can be accomplished in
    'a .Net application within the context of an Integration Services control flow. 

    'Expand the other regions which have "Help" prefixes for examples of specific ways to use
    'Integration Services features within this script task.
    #End Region
    Option Strict Off

    #Region "Imports"
    Imports System
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Math
    Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

    #End Region

    'ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    'or parent of this class.
    <Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()> _
    <System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
    Partial Public Class ScriptMain
        Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

        Private _app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Private _books As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks
        Private _book As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Protected _sheets As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets
        Protected _sheet1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet


    #Region "Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script"
        'To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
        'either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
        'the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
        'code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
        'Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
        'ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
        'To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.

        'Example of reading from a variable:
        ' startTime = Dts.Variables("System::StartTime").Value

        'Example of writing to a variable:
        ' Dts.Variables("User::myStringVariable").Value = "new value"

        'Example of reading from a package parameter:
        ' batchId = Dts.Variables("$Package::batchId").Value

        'Example of reading from a project parameter:
        ' batchId = Dts.Variables("$Project::batchId").Value

        'Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
        ' batchId = Dts.Variables("$Project::batchId").GetSensitiveValue()
    #End Region

    #Region "Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script"
        'This script task can fire events for logging purposes.

        'Example of firing an error event:
        ' Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0)

        'Example of firing an information event:
        ' Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, fireAgain)

        'Example of firing a warning event:
        ' Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0)
    #End Region

    #Region "Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script"
        'Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
        '"Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.

        'Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
        ' Dim rawConnection As Object = Dts.Connections("Sales DB").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction)
        ' Dim myADONETConnection As SqlConnection = CType(rawConnection, SqlConnection)
        ' <Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection>
        ' Dts.Connections("Sales DB").ReleaseConnection(rawConnection)

        'Example of using a File connection manager
        ' Dim rawConnection As Object = Dts.Connections("Prices.zip").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction)
        ' Dim filePath As String = CType(rawConnection, String)
        ' <Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection>
        ' Dts.Connections("Prices.zip").ReleaseConnection(rawConnection)
    #End Region

        'This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        'Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        'To open Help, press F1.

        Public Sub Main()

            Try
                Dim FileName As String = ""
                If Dts.Variables.Contains("DestinationPath") = True Then
                    FileName = CType(Dts.Variables("DestinationPath").Value, String)
                End If

                OpenExcelWorkbook(FileName)

                _sheet1 = CType(_sheets(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
                _sheet1.Activate()

                Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = _sheet1.Rows(2)
                range.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)
                DoRelease(range)
                DoRelease(_sheet1)
                CloseExcelWorkbook()
                DoRelease(_book)
                _app.Quit()
                DoRelease(_app)
                Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try


        End Sub
        Protected Sub OpenExcelWorkbook(ByVal fileName As String)
            'try
            '{
            _app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
            If _book Is Nothing Then
                _books = _app.Workbooks
                _book = _books.Open(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
                _sheets = _book.Worksheets
            End If
            '}
            'catch(Exception ex)
            '{
            ' Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            '}

        End Sub
        Protected Sub CloseExcelWorkbook()
            _book.Save()
            _book.Close(False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        End Sub
        Protected Sub DoRelease(ByVal o As Object)
            Try
                If Not o Is Nothing Then
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o)
                End If
            Finally
                o = Nothing
            End Try
        End Sub

    #Region "ScriptResults declaration"
        'This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        'result of the script.

        'This code was generated automatically.
        Enum ScriptResults
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        End Enum

    #End Region

    End Class
```

The Excel file is reached by the variable "DestinationPath". This path works when outside the script (ie it can fill data in the file in a previous step). It also works when in BIDS in the script. I have also made sure to make it available to the script as a ReadOnlyVariable. So I am pretty confident that it is not a problem with the variable.

My server is a Windows 2012 R2 (64-bit)

The package is being executed on an SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.

I have installed Excel 2013 on the server.

I have created the following folder as this could also cause the problem (I have read): C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

The caller of my script is my administrator userid - and this userid is capable of using Excel on the server.

Comment: In my Main(), if I comment out the lines from OpenExcelWorkbook(FileName) to DoRelease(_app) it will no longer fail. It seems to fail on the OpenExcelWorkbook command.

Comment: Excel Interop requires Excel to be present on the server. What are you trying to do? The script doesn't seem to be doing anything with data.

Comment: Problem is solved now. But the script did look in the sheet and deleted line number 2. I had a dummy line 2 in order to format my data in Excel correct. But all has been solved by using the answer from Troy Witthoeft below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason we couldn't use the regular Excel Connection manager to insert data, and instead of deleting line 2, just never send it?  Use a Conditional Split to siphon it off.  Here is a [simple example](http://oakdome.com/programming/SSIS_DataTransform.php).  Here is an [advanced example](https://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/) of using SSIS default Excel Connection manager.  I'd also like to grant a pearl of wisdom against using Interop.Excel inside of script tasks.  It can certainly lead to these types of "But, it works on my Machine" scenarios. Read [KB257757](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) to see why Microsoft discourages this type of thing.  However, some things only Interop.Excel can do, such as saving to PDF or running macros.  You're not doing either of those things, so why not give the regular Excel connector a try?

Comment: This seems very promising! I haven't got it to work yet - I will set the answer as accepted if it solves my problem :-). Regarding line 2: It was there from the beginning. This was the only way I could format my columns. But seems as if this can be done directly from the Excel Connection manager too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!!! Will look more into how to let it use the first sheet in Excel as the solution I have right now is creating a new sheet (as specified in the "Simple example" above).

Comment: Dough... I simply had to drag the new sheet in Excel so it is now number 1 sheet. Simple as that :-)